# How to configure DB2 CLI driver on Windows 7 64bit for Cognos BI Framework Manager?

Tags: db2, cognos-bi

I am using Framework Manager (the data modeling tool) for Cognos Business Intelligence (v10.1).

I have a successful setup of DB2 (v9.7) and Cognos BI on AIX machine. On my Windows machine I want to do some changes in my model that connects with DB2 at AIX.

I have added E:\softwares\v9.7fp7_ntx64_odbc_cli\clidriver\bin to my Path environmental variable. This path contains **db2cli.dll**. That resolves my error `UDA-SQL-0569 Unable to load the driver manager library ( db2cli.dll ).`

Now I am getting following error.

> QE-DEF-0285 The logon failed.
>   QE-DEF-0325 The logon failed for the following reason:
>   RQP-DEF-0068 Unable to connect to at least one database during a multi-database attach to 1 database(s) in: 
>    CampaignDS 
>      UDA-SQL-0570 Unable to resolve ODBC function ( sqledosd_api ).

What else I have to do to connect my Framework Manager successfully? Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should install the IBM Data Server client in order to connect to a DB2 server/database.

I am not sure that just copying a dll will be enough to allow a DB2 connection via ODBC.

The best is to configure the client, and the configure it:

- Catalog the instance
- Catalog the database
- Configure the ODBC source

Download the drivers for DB2 (client) from this link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878